# Is there any faster way to browse the DBML designer?

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

You know in Visual Studio when you open your .DBML and it's just this huge 2D plane full of tables? I have to scroll around and I can never find what I am looking for very quickly. I tried pressing the keyboard key of the starting letter of the tables thinking I may be able to jump around, no luck. There ought to be a drop down list at the top of table names so I can just hop to them. I literally just scrolled around for like 5 minutes and I still haven't found the table I am looking for even though I know it is there. That's when I decided to ask this question. (This has got to be one of the all time worst ideas for an interface.)

Comment: Plus one for the worst idea for an interface.

Comment: And when you open it (by mistake of course) with a lot of tables, you're gonna have a bad time, or at least Visual Studio is gonna have a bad time... even with i7 quad core 8G RAM + SSD, I just prefer to put VS out of misery than waiting the designer to load...

Answer (score 0):

I will assume this is a question and not just a rant.  Is there a way to search the designer file to find a specific table?  No, there isn't.

The best way I know to manage this is to use multiple DBML files, each containing one logical group of associated tables.  If you put all tables from your database into one DBML file, it will be difficult to manage and navigate.